# Node Exporter docker container not working (HTTP 426) with `network_mode: host`

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus-node-exporter

I've been following the instructions from Node Exporter's [official documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#docker) and running **Node Exporter** in my Docker Compose project.

```yaml
# compose.yaml

...
services:
  ...
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:v.1.7.0
    command:
      - '--path.rootfs=/host'
    network_mode: host
    pid: host
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /:/host:ro,rslave
...
```

This does start the container and the log doesn't show any error, but navigating to `localhost:9100` gets me HTTP Error 426 "Upgrade Required". Same when querying the `/metrics` endpoint via curl, Postman or whatever.

If I replace `network_mode: host` with

```
ports:
  - 9100:9100/tcp
```

it works just fine. But then it it not clear to me if this is still ok (given the official docs' warning).

In other words the two questions are:

1. Why is `network_mode: host` not working?
2. What are the contraindications of not using it?

I am using Docker Desktop and WSL2 Ubuntu.

Comment: This question problems: 1. It has two not-really related questions, making it unfocused. 2. Both of them are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Additionally, your approach will result in metrics being shown for your WSL Ubuntu VM, and I'm not 100% they will match proper metrics from host. Is that OK? If you'll decide to ask on other sites of network, I'd recommend to address this beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out host network driver is [not supported in Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/).

This might answer question #1.